# Crontab not working (standard troubleshooting done)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

* * * * * /home/VI/vserver/jira_extractor/bash_scripts/cronbg.sh
```

- I edit crontab with `crontab -e` as a local user.
- Cron is running `root      7296     1  0 17:28 ?        00:00:00
  /usr/sbin/cron -f`
- My script runs when using exactly the same path as specified in the
  crontab
- There is an empty line at the end of the crontab script.
- I have specified that crontab will run in bash shell

Any hints on trouble shooting will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't see a path specified in the crontab you are showing. An incorrect or incomplete PATH setting is usually what causes this kind of failure scenario. Also, `cron` sends an email to the owner of the crontab on the system. So if you can get your local mail on that system, it should tell you what the error is.

Comment: @Jake : For debugging, I would write the command in the crontab as `/bin/bash -x /home/VI/vserver/jira_extractor/bash_scripts/cronbg.sh >/home/VI/cronbg.log 2>&1` and see whether you get a log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, adding the environment variables in the bash scripts to my crontab file solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Does the user allow to run `cron`?
Print out `/etc/cron.allow` & `/etc/cron.deny`.

Crontab troubleshooting will require to check log file `/var/log/syslog`. Assuming that user is allowed to run `cron`, then there will be an entry when your schedule job is run.

Ref: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto